# How to load gif using STB in C++

Tags: c++, image, textures, gif

I'm using STB to load png and other images.
https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h
It works with static images.

But I don't know how to load animaged gif.
Comment in STB points me to https://gist.github.com/urraka/685d9a6340b26b830d49
But it no longer works.
And comments in there are point back to STB to function called `stbi_load_gif_from_memory` .

And STB have function `stbi_load_gif_from_memory`, but there are no comments at all.
And calling `stbi_load_gif_from_memory` isn't obvious to me.

Can somebody show sample code how to use it ?

Comment: Why don't you use this STB's issues https://github.com/nothings/stb/issues

Comment: Should be self-explanatory I think? `int *comp, int req_comp` are same as in other functions. `int *x, int *y, int *z` x,y is size, z is frame count. `int **delays` is frame lengths, presumably you give it a pointer to uninitialized `int *delays`, and it allocates the array for you. The return buffer is probably tightly packed with consecutive frames.

Comment: Once you said it, it seem more obvious.
I tested it and it seem works as you said.
Thank you.
Just one more think to be sure.
Once I'm done with it I free both buffer and delays with stbi_image_free ?
`stbi_image_free(buffer);stbi_image_free(delays);`